# Getting network printers from remote user, can variable be used in path?

Tags: powershell, networking, printing

I am getting the network printers from a remote user by getting the SID and querying the registry.

When I hard-code the SID in the path, it correctly displays the network printers for that user.
When I **use a variable** for the SID it fails with this error:
"Cannot find path '\HKEY_Users\Printers\Connections' because it does not exist. At line:18 char:7"

Here is the code:

```
# Get network connected printers from remote user by:
# 1) Connecting to computer name
# 2) Getting user and SID from AD
# 3) Query registry value

$MySAM = 'xyz1234'
$searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$MySAM))"
$user = $searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry() 

# get binary SID from AD account
$binarySID = $user.ObjectSid.Value

# convert to string SID
$stringSID = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($binarySID,0)).Value

# computer name
$computer = 'xyz123456'

$Session = New-PSSession $computer  -ErrorAction Stop # try to remote connect

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock  { 

# works when SID hard-coded into path
# Get-ChildItem "Registry::\HKEY_Users\S-1-5-21-2009805145-1601463483-1839490880-13975\Printers\Connections" 

# fails when using SID variable
Get-ChildItem "Registry::\HKEY_Users\$stringSID\Printers\Connections"
} 
       
Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
```

Comment: As you have noticed, there is not a "variable" that lets you specify "user that's currently logged onto a remote computer" (which is a vague concept anyway: What about multi-user RDS servers, for example?). In 99999 cases out of 100000 the best answer is "run the code as that user rather than trying to access per-user data remotely" (e.g., as a logon script).

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you set `$stringSID` before connecting to the remote session. This means `$stringSID` will be blank on the remote machine since it's a (mostly) separate environment. However, you can specify that you want variables from your *local* session with the `$Using:var` scope. A good example is to try both out:

```
$Hello = 'Hello'
$World = 'World'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemotePC {
  Write-Output $Hello $using:World
}

World
```

---

Another issue you may have have is the registry hive for other users may not get loaded in a remote session. We can fix it manually by `LOAD`ing it with the old `REG` tool. As a bonus, you can get the currently logged in user on the remote machine, and use their username instead of SID:

```
# example to get the currently logged-on user: (in DOMAIN\Username format). 
# note: returns nothing if multiple users logged in (through RDP etc)
$LoggedOnUser = (Get-CimInstance -class Win32_ComputerSystem).username

# split the domain section of the username off:
$Username = ($LoggedOnUser -split '\\')[1]

# load the user's registry hive to an easy to find path:
REG LOAD "HKEY_USERS\$Username" "C:\Users\$Username\NTUSER.DAT"
# Now you can search their registry
Get-ChildItem "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$Username\Printers\Connections"
```